# Comparing Lines Within a Single File

Tags: perl

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing what I am attempting. I have a need to read a file and compare each line of the file with all the ones following it. (i.e. compare line 1 with lines 2,3,4,5,...; line 2 with 3,4,5,...; line 3 with 4,5... etc). I feel some of the files are too large to read entirely into @lists, so I do this now by opening two file handles to the same file and use tell and seek to get the position of one file and set the position of the other something like this:

```
open FH1, '/arf/test.txt';
open FH2, '/arf/test.txt';

while ($outer = <FH1>){
    chomp($outer);
    $fh1Posn = tell FH1;
    seek FH2, $fh1Posn, 0;
    while ($inner = <FH2>){
        [code to compare line];
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine in small files, but is a drag with some of the larger files I need to process (even when I substitute dummy code for the comparison portion). Perhaps this is to be expected, but I'm wondering if there is anything I could try to speed up the just the reading of the file? I was thinking  of just using a single file handle, eliminating the second and using $fh1Posn at the bottom of the while loop to reset the cursor back to where it was at the top, something like:

```
open FH1, '/arf/test.txt';

while ($outer = <FH1>){
    chomp($outer);
    $fh1Posn = tell FH1;
    while ($inner = <FH1>){
        [code to compare line];
    }
    seek FH1, $fh1Posn, 0;
}
```

Haven't tried this yet - will do so - but feel it probably won't do anything worth the trouble.

Comment: Interesting question. May be use streaming rather then read whole file at once.

Comment: The number of comparisons you perform will grow exponentially (?) with the number of lines in your file (exponentially is probably the wrong term, but it's been a while since I've worked with series). If you really want to improve performance, you need to improve your algorithm. Can you reduce the problem set by sorting, for example? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve that requires you to do so many comparisons?

Comment: You're right it would grow whatever-entially. This is to be used for testing a searching and scoring algorithm. We want to score each line in a file against all the remaining lines. If that line scores within a certain threshhold, we will then want to check whether our search criteria would have allowed the first record to find the second. Since the idea is to locate the ones which scored high, but wouldn't have been found during a search, we want to process everything against everything else. It's okay if it runs long, I just want to cut runtime as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution would be to do it entirely in memory, limiting your reading of the disk to just a single pass.  If you don't have enough memory to do that though, then I suggest splitting it in chunks.

You're current solution is to read the file O(n^2) times is the worst case solution with not enough memory.  If you do it in groups of 1000 lines, you can reduce your disk operations considerably.  You'd have to experiment to find where you real memory limit is of course.

```
my $buffersize = 1000;

open FH1, '/arf/test.txt';
open FH2, '/arf/test.txt';

while (! eof(FH1)) {
    my @buffer = ();
    for (1..$buffersize) {
        my $outer = <FH1>;
        chomp $outer;
        push @buffer, $outer;
        last if eof(FH1);
    }

    # Seek code here

    while ($inner = <FH2>){
        for (@buffer) {
            [code to compare line];
        }
    }
}
```

**Addendum on Friday, Feb 25th - More Detailed Code Solution**

I had some additional time at the end of the day, so I coded up a version of this that works on a file named test.txt that contains the numbers 1-10 on each line.  I therefore configured the buffersize to just 4 so that the script does 4 passes of the file instead of 11, like your original method would.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $buffersize = 4; # 1000;
my $file = 'test.txt'; # '/arf/test.txt';

open my $fh1, '<', $file;
open my $fh2, '<', $file;

while (! eof($fh1)) {

    # Move fh2 to start of buffer
    my $startofbuffer = tell($fh1);
    seek($fh2, $startofbuffer, 0);

    # Build Buffer of entries to compare
    my @buffer = ();
    for (1..$buffersize) {
        chomp(my $outer = <$fh1>);
        print "buffer, $.\n";
        push @buffer, $outer;
        last if eof($fh1);
    }

    # Keep track of relative offset to start of buffer
    for (my $offset = 0; !eof($fh2); $offset++) {
        chomp(my $inner = <$fh2>);

        for my $i (0..$#buffer) {
            last if $i >= $offset;
            my $outer = $buffer[$i];
            print "Compare outer $outer to inner $inner\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is as follows

```
buffer, 1
buffer, 2
buffer, 3
buffer, 4
Compare outer 1 to inner 2
Compare outer 1 to inner 3
Compare outer 2 to inner 3
Compare outer 1 to inner 4
Compare outer 2 to inner 4
Compare outer 3 to inner 4
Compare outer 1 to inner 5
Compare outer 2 to inner 5
Compare outer 3 to inner 5
Compare outer 4 to inner 5
Compare outer 1 to inner 6
Compare outer 2 to inner 6
Compare outer 3 to inner 6
Compare outer 4 to inner 6
Compare outer 1 to inner 7
Compare outer 2 to inner 7
Compare outer 3 to inner 7
Compare outer 4 to inner 7
Compare outer 1 to inner 8
Compare outer 2 to inner 8
Compare outer 3 to inner 8
Compare outer 4 to inner 8
Compare outer 1 to inner 9
Compare outer 2 to inner 9
Compare outer 3 to inner 9
Compare outer 4 to inner 9
Compare outer 1 to inner 10
Compare outer 2 to inner 10
Compare outer 3 to inner 10
Compare outer 4 to inner 10
buffer, 5
buffer, 6
buffer, 7
buffer, 8
Compare outer 5 to inner 6
Compare outer 5 to inner 7
Compare outer 6 to inner 7
Compare outer 5 to inner 8
Compare outer 6 to inner 8
Compare outer 7 to inner 8
Compare outer 5 to inner 9
Compare outer 6 to inner 9
Compare outer 7 to inner 9
Compare outer 8 to inner 9
Compare outer 5 to inner 10
Compare outer 6 to inner 10
Compare outer 7 to inner 10
Compare outer 8 to inner 10
buffer, 9
buffer, 10
Compare outer 9 to inner 10
```

**Addendum on Sunday, Mar 2nd - Benchmarks**

Your report of no improvement in speed made me a little curious, so I created a little script to make some fake data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $lines = shift or die "Missing line count\n";
die "Lines outside of range 1 - 1,000,000" if $lines < 1 or $lines > 1_000_000;

my $fakedata = 70;

my $filename = 'fd' . sprintf("%06d", $lines) . '.txt';

open my $fh, '>', $filename;

for my $i (1..$lines) {
    my $fake = join '', map {('a'..'z')[int rand 26]} (1..$fakedata);

    $fh->print("$i fake${fake}fake\n");
}

close $fh;

print "Created $filename\n";

1;

__END__
```

I then edited the detailed code I provided above so that it didn't output any debugging statments and instead did a very basis comparison.  This led to the following results for files with line counts of 1_000, 10_000 and 20_000.

```
                For Buffer size, show Time in sec and (# of File Reads)
                --------------------------------------------------------
File by lines   b = 1        b = 10      b = 100     b = 1k      b = 10k  
-------------   -----        ------      -------     ------      -------  
Lines = 1k      t = 1.54s    t = 0.35s   t = 0.22s   t = 0.21             
Size = 88k      r = (1001)   r = (101)   r = (11)    r = (2)              
Tests = 500k                                                              

Lines = 10k     t = 185s     t = 35s     t = 23s     t = 21.7s   t = 21.5s
Size = 899k     r = (10k)    r = (1k)    r = (101)   r = (11)    r = (2)  
Tests = 50m                                                               

Lines = 20k     t = 593s     t = 136s    t = 90s     t = 86s     t = 85.5s
Size = 1.8m     r = (20k)    r = (2k)    r = (201)   r = (21)    r = (3)  
Tests = 200m
```

As you can see, the buffering even just 100, brought the script time down by an order of 5 or more.   These scripts still take a long time though, as the number of comparisons is equal to N * N / 2.  That's 200 million tests for the 20k file, which is why you can see the time it takes to do that file be 4 times as long as the 10k file.

If these values were to hold true, your 250k length file would take 156.25 times longer than the 20k file.  That equates to 3.71 hours in the best case scenario with buffering or 25.7 hours without buffering at all.  These numbers even assume the absolute minimum time for comparison, and I assume yours is probably more complicated than a simple old/even test.

Unfortunately, you don't say anything about the nature of your project and these comparisons, so I can't really conjecture on other possible speed improvements.  If I were to assume that your goal was more of the nature of sorting, then it would be possible to reduce your comparisons to O(n log n) instead of O(N**2).  For sorting I'd advise you break the file into groups able to fit into memory, use perl sort to sort them, and then use a merge sort to merge the sorted groups.  I won't bother providing more detailed code though since it's just conjecture that's what you're up to.

Anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Looks like I'll have to do something clever to reposition the second cursor with `seek` - perhaps have a second @list to hold the return from `tell` for for each line being read and then use that to reposition the second file handle. I think I can handle that.

Comment: Obviously this method relies on the fact that it not be required to compare the 1st line to all other lines before other compares.  I had some more time at the end of the day, so I made an expanded example of the concept with working fake data.

Comment: Wow. I cannot tell you how grateful I am for your help. I pretty much coded the same thing during the night with a couple of differences and kept getting wrong answers. I'll give this a go and will add a comment to let you know how I did.

Comment: Yes, I'd be curious to here how it turned out, since I can't predict without knowing more about the nature of your comparison and project.  Good luck.

Comment: Made the changes and everything is working as expected, but haven't gotten any performance boost. In order to measure performance, my test file contains approximately 250,000 records. I've increased the buffer from 1,000 to 10,000 and finally to 100,000 and can see a slight impact in the process' memory usage, but nothing in terms of performance. I'm thinking the buffering might actually be better served on the inner loop rather than the outer - since that's the one where I'm re-reading the entire file for each record in the outer loop. Will do this tomorrow. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: What do you mean the buffer might be better served in the inner loop rather the outer loop? That doesn't make any sense to me.  I've went and did some benchmarking of the script that I provided to you, and have included the results of those tests in this answer.  Ultimately, if you want to test speed improvements for your script, I'd advise using a much smaller data file, so 10,000 lines max based off of what I observed.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. What I said doesn't make any sense to me, either; I guess I was starting to over think things. I'd been pulled off to a different project for the last few days and am ready to get back to this with a fresh mind. I think I have too many 'moving parts' in my script right now to be able to effectively gauge the benefits of the buffering. Time to simplify and scale down a bit (as you suggest) and, once I know that file handling isn't the problem start building up again.